# Pixel Tactics - static stat modifiers and damage calculations

Tags: pixel-tactics

Recently I was playing a game of Pixel Tactics and I had a scenario where a card in my middle row was giving the card in front of it +2 life.  The card in front had damage counters from a previous wave equal to its original life, but, due to its supporter, was still alive.

If I moved the card in front to a different position (say, in front of my leader), would the lethal damage cause it to be defeated instantly because the damage occurred in a previous wave?